# migrate AWS Lambda rails code to AWS Fargate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-fargate

I have AWS Lambda function written in ruby and due to the larger and larger amounts of data it should process (maths) it timeouts. Due to the nature of the job it is timing out due to very extensive maths and optimization of maths is out of review - it is way more complex and not an option as sits in a proprietary library written in ruby.

To avoid this I'm searching the way to migrate whole lambda code to AWS Fargate so it will be able to instantiate a task and let it run for a long time (probably around 30-35 minutes).  I was not able to find a guide on how to convert lambda code to aws fargate deployment.

So I have an AWS lambda zip file that contains rails lambda code, proprietary ruby library, and mysql2 gem with native *.so libraries (results of calculations are stored in db).

Is there any tool or guide how to migrate such or similar lambda functions to fargate? Btw, lambda is invoked from SQS as far as I understood in case of Fargate SQS will invoke lambda which will run fargate task. But task configuration and images and rest are not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sngsnd Thanks for asking the question.
As per the definition,

> AWS Fargate is a serverless compute engine for containers.

Below steps may help you.

1. Containerized your Ruby code.
2. Put image in repository like (DockerHub, ECR etc)
3. Create task definition in ECS
4. Create ECS cluster.
5. Create Service to run your task.

This article may help you.
[serverless-application-for-long-running-process-fargate-lambda](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-application-for-long-running-process-fargate-lambda)

Comment: Thank you, @Hasmukh Rathod
One question which is still open is exactly covered by the 1st point of your answer:
**How can I create a container our of my RoR lambda deployment package?** 

I know that there are docker images of lambda environments including RoR env - actually I build mysql2 native libs using such image. But how to deploy my RoR package onto such an image and how to make calls to my code? Any routing/configuration samples? Again, if it were just a normal ror application I wouldn't be asking this, but lambda isn't, that's why I'm still confused.